# Sorting XML file

Tags: xml, dom

I need to sort an XML by tag names and attribute.
Is it possible using DOM?

I need the result in a sorted XML file not HTML.

for example:

```
<books>
    <book id='1'>
        <name value='N1'/>
        <author value='A1'/>
    </book>
    <book id='3'>
        <name value='N3'/>
        <author value='A3'/>
    </book>
    <book id='2'>
        <author value='A2'/>
        <name value='N2'/>
    </book>
</books>
```

I expect to get after sortXML ('id')

```
<books>
    <book id='1'>
        <author value='A1'/>
        <name value='N1'/>      
    </book>
    <book id='2'>
        <author value='A2'/>
        <name value='N2'/>
    </book>
    <book id='3'>
        <author value='A3'/>
        <name value='N3'/>      
    </book>
</books>
```

XML is sorted by **tag names** then by **id**

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but why do you want to sort your XML? Relying on the order of elements is unwise in my understanding of XML. Happy to be corrected though :)

Comment: @Tom Duckering: For displaying purposes i guess?

Answer (score 3):

You could write an XSL that sorts your data using the [sort-element](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp) and transform you XML document with it, if your DOM implementation supports XSL Transformations.

Alternatively you could fetch all elements to an array and implement a sorting algorithm, e.g. [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), to sort the elements of the array.

Or, if you are using the .Net DOM you could use a sorting XPath query. XPath does not support sorting by itself, but the .Net implementation provides the [`XPathExpression.AddSort` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathexpression.addsort.aspx).

Comment: Great response (overall) .. +1

Answer (score 1):

Using java:

- create a list of 'Element'
- loop over all the elements 'book' under 'books' and add it to the list
- detach all the 'book' from the parent 'books'
- sort your list using a custom `Comparator<Element>`

  Comparator< Element >
         {
         int compareTo(Element a,Element b)
                {
                /* compare the values of a/author and b/author */
                } 
         }
- loop over all the Element in your list and insert it back to 'books'

Using xslt:

see xsl:for-each and [xsl:sort](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add the xsl suggested by Vinz:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="books">
        <books>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="book">
                <xsl:sort select="@id" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </books>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="book">
        <book>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="local-name()" data-type="text" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </book>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the YAML processor [mikefarah/yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) to sort XML.

**Version < 4.30**

`yq --input-format xml --output-format xml '.books.book |= (sort_by(.+id) | .. | sort_keys(.))'`

**Version >= 4.30**

`yq --input-format xml --output-format xml '.books.book |=  (sort_by(.+@id) | .. | sort_keys(.))'`

`sort_by(.+@id)` sorts the array elements.
`sort_keys(.)` sorts the keys inside every item.

**Output**

```xml
<books>
  <book id="1">
    <author value="A1"></author>
    <name value="N1"></name>
  </book>
  <book id="2">
    <author value="A2"></author>
    <name value="N2"></name>
  </book>
  <book id="3">
    <author value="A3"></author>
    <name value="N3"></name>
  </book>
</books>
```